# Python3 Tk Question About Multiple Expandable Entry Fields

Tags: python, python-3.x, dictionary, tkinter, frontend

I am still really new to python and even newer to tk. I will start by explaining what I am trying to do because I am starting to struggle but I could be taking the wrong approach to some tasks. In the picture below you can see the front end. The high level is I am making an app to interface between a PLC and a raspberry PI to save some machine data to a SQL database. I have all the backend working well, just working on the front end.

Basically the user will fillout how many tags they want to store. In the example below is 3. Then 3 sets of input fields appear when the update is selected. This is working. However my goal is to shift these into the scrolling box below. So if the user were to add a large number it would be scrollable (Problem 1)

The bigger issue I am having right now is with actually saving my data. I will need to implement a database to this front end so when you "update" it would save the current values into the database so next time the app is launched it would remember what you inputted last time. Currently I am trying to build a dictionary off the inputs into the entry box but when I put something into the top set of fields they populate all the way down instantly. This makes sense based on how my code is laid out. I am not exactly sure how to address this is a good manor.

The update_command in the code below is where I am trying to show the right number of fields based on the tag selection. Then also populate the dictionary. In the output you can see there is only 1 item in the dictionary. There should be a list of 3 sets of data. I am not sure if this is because they are all duplicating currently instead of allowing me to individually set them.

Front End App
[image: Front End Picture]

The current output
[image: Current Output]

```
from tkinter import *
import sys

#Get Selected Row From Selector List & Populate Fields
def get_selected_row(event):
    index=list1.curselection()[0]
    selected_tuple = list1.get(index)
    e1.delete(0,END)
    e1.insert(END,selected_tuple[0])
    e2.delete(0,END)
    e2.insert(END,selected_tuple[1])
    e3.delete(0,END)
    e3.insert(END,selected_tuple[2])
    e4.delete(0,END)
    e4.insert(END,selected_tuple[3])
    e5.delete(0,END)
    e5.insert(END,selected_tuple[4])
    e6.delete(0,END)
    e6.insert(END,selected_tuple[5])
    e7.delete(0,END)
    e7.insert(END,selected_tuple[6])
    e8.delete(0,END)
    e8.insert(END,selected_tuple[7])
    e9.delete(0,END)
    e9.insert(END,selected_tuple[8])
    e10.delete(0,END)
    e10.insert(END,selected_tuple[9])
    e11.delete(0,END)
    e11.insert(END,selected_tuple[10])
    e12.delete(0,END)
    e12.insert(END,selected_tuple[11])
    e13.delete(0,END)
    e13.insert(END,selected_tuple[12])
    e14.delete(0,END)
    e14.insert(END,selected_tuple[13])
    e15.delete(0,END)
    e15.insert(END,selected_tuple[14])
    e16.delete(0,END)
    e16.insert(END,selected_tuple[15])
    e17.delete(0,END)
    e17.insert(END,selected_tuple[16])

def exit_command():
    #BackEnd.close()
    window.destroy
    sys.exit(0)

def update_command():
    #Selector List Starts At Row 3
    NumberOfTagsInt = int(NumberOfTags.get())
    print("Number Of Tags")
    print(NumberOfTagsInt)
    number = 0
    if NumberOfTagsInt > 0:
        for item in range(0,NumberOfTagsInt):
            #Define Name Of Widgets To Prevent Having Duplicate Names
            listlabel = "l00"
            entrylabel = "100"
            entrylabel2 = "100"
            entrylabel3 = "100"
            listlabel = "L" + listlabel + str(number)
            entrylabel = "E1" + entrylabel + str(number)
            entrylabel2 = "E2" + entrylabel2 + str(number)
            entrylabel3 = "E3" + entrylabel3 + str(number)
            number = number+1

            #Select The Starting Row For Display List Starts At Row 3
            rowvar = 3 + number

            #Create Label Based On Tag #
            listlabel = Label(window, text="Tag "+str(number))
            listlabel.grid(row=rowvar,column=0, sticky="E")

            entrylabel = Entry(window,textvariable=tagname)
            entrylabel.grid(row=rowvar, column=1, sticky=E+W, columnspan = 1)
            entrylabel2 = Entry(window,textvariable=tagtype)
            entrylabel2.grid(row=rowvar, column=2, sticky=E+W, columnspan = 1)
            entrylabel3 = Entry(window,textvariable=triggertag)
            entrylabel3.grid(row=rowvar, column=3, sticky=E+W, columnspan = 1)

            print(tagname.get())
            print(tagtype.get())
            print(triggertag.get())


            #Create Dynamic List Of Data
            datasets = []
            datasets.append({"TagNumber":number,"TagName":tagname.get(), "TagType" : tagtype.get(), "TriggerTag" : triggertag.get()} )
    print(datasets)


#Let User Know Database Is Connecting
init_window = Tk()
init_window.title("GVS Datalog")
photo = PhotoImage(file = 'GlobalLogo_Transparent.png')
init_window.iconphoto(False, photo)
l0 = Label(init_window, text="Connecting To Database... This May Take Several Minutes.")
l0.grid(row=0,column=0)

init_window.update_idletasks()
init_window.update()
#import GVSDatalog
init_window.destroy()
# End Of User Notification

window  = Tk()
window.title("GVS Data Logger V1.0 Written By Kevin Lay")
photo = PhotoImage(file = 'GlobalLogo_Transparent.png')
window.iconphoto(False, photo)

#Label Definitions 
l1 = Label(window, text="PLC IP Address")
l1.grid(row=0,column=0, sticky="E")

l2 = Label(window, text="Number Of Tags To Store")
l2.grid(row=1, column=0, sticky="E")

l3 = Label(window, text="Tag #")
l3.grid(row=2, column=0, sticky="E")

l4 = Label(window, text="Tag Name")
l4.grid(row=2, column=1, sticky="E")

l5 = Label(window, text="Tag Type")
l5.grid(row=2, column=2, sticky="E")

l6 = Label(window, text="Trigger Tag")
l6.grid(row=2, column=3, sticky="E")


#Entry Box Definitions (Need To Change To View Only)
#Variables
PLCIpaddress= StringVar()
NumberOfTags = StringVar()
tagname = StringVar()
tagtype = StringVar()
triggertag = StringVar()

#Main Entry Points At Top Of Project
e1 = Entry(window,textvariable=PLCIpaddress)
e1.grid(row=0, column=1, sticky=E+W, columnspan = 3)

e2 = Entry(window,textvariable=NumberOfTags)
e2.grid(row=1, column=1, sticky=E+W, columnspan = 3)

#List Box For Displaying Data
list1 = Listbox (window, height=25, width=200)
list1.grid(row=9, column=0, rowspan = 25, columnspan = 4)

#Scroll Button Creation
sb1 = Scrollbar(window)
sb1.grid(row=9, column=5, rowspan=25, sticky=N+S+W)

sb2 = Scrollbar(window, orient='horizontal')
sb2.grid(row=35, column=0, columnspan=4, sticky=E+W)

#Configuration Of Scroll and List Box Interaction
list1.configure(yscrollcommand=sb1.set)
list1.configure(xscrollcommand=sb2.set)
sb1.config(command=list1.yview)
sb2.config(command=list1.xview)

#Configure The Selector
list1.bind('<<ListboxSelect>>', get_selected_row)

#Button Definitions
b1=Button(window,text="Close", width=12, command = exit_command)
b1.grid(row=11, column=6)

b2=Button(window,text="Update", width=12, command = update_command)
b2.grid(row=12, column=6)

while True:
    window.mainloop()
```

Comment: If you write lengthy paragraphs explaining what your app is, people are going to miss out on the actual problem. Make sure to focus only on the problem and also provide a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)

Comment: The program will not run: `ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'GVSDatalog'`

Comment: I apologize. I forgot to comment that line out. It is not required for testing the application. I have made the edit to the post.

Comment: Your basic problem is that you're using the same `StringVar`s for each row in your table - this makes them all display the same data, since there's no place for them to store individual data.  You need something like a list of `StringVar`s, instead.  Also, it's pointless to call `.get()` on these Vars immediately after creating the Entries, the user can't possibly have typed anything into them yet.

Comment: I agree jason, but Im not sure exactly when I should trigger the .get() function. Right now you would do it with no data in it, but then when you add data and hit update it would run the .get() again. But logically it seems not exactly correct.

Comment: @KevinLay: Just a note: you don't need to put `root.mainloop()` inside of a `while` loop; `root.mainloop()` already runs a loop itself. Unless, of course, you want the window to continually try to open after it is closed. I also suggest removing `width=200` from `list1 = Listbox(window, ...)`. On lower-quality screens (like mine), it makes the window so wide that it pushes the buttons off the right edge.